# elFinder Issue with double clicking files

Tags: elfinder

I have integrated elFinder with an Asp.Net Mvc application using the information [here](http://www.leniel.net/2013/04/manage-folders-and-files-in-your-aspnet-mvc-project-with-elfinder-net-file-manager.html).

Whenever a user double clicks a file the filesystem's path to the file is sent to the browser instead of the URL path.  However using the download button works perfectly. The files are in a folder not under the web folder.

Anyone seen this before? Know of a fix?

I am assuming the files (and their) paths are stored locally since I do not see a call to the server to "open" the file. I do see a server call to "open" folders. If that's the case it would appear the file path isn't being converted to the url path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up adding this option

```
            getFileCallback: function(file, fm) {
                $('#elfinder').elfinder('instance').exec('download');
            }
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: Didn't work for me (`v 2.1_n (Nightly: 477fc6f)`), yet just adds a second open/save/cancel dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can also overwrite the doubleclick handler

```
//
var elf = $('#elfinder').elfinder(
{
    url: 'example.com/connector.php',
    //Other settings
    handlers:
    {
        dblclick: function(event, elfinderInstance)
        {
            elfinderInstance.exec('download');
        }
    }
}).elfinder('instance');
```

Comment: It does exactly the same thing of the original `elfinderInstance.exec('getfile')`.

Comment: I think `return false;` is needed in `dblclick` handler